# How do I add a custom domain with 'on other DNS' option to a static web app with Azure CLi

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-static-web-app, custom-domain

I would like to add a custom domain that is managed by AWS to my Azure Static Web App. Microsoft documentation shows how to add one if the DNS is managed by Azure itself. Sadly, I cannot find anything for my use case. To be more clear, the function I'd like to use with Azure command line is shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUhDR.png) picture.

I have tried `az staticwebapp hostname set --name FOO --hostname BAR.com` which doesn't work.

Comment: I suppose you have already configured CNAME/TXT/ALIAS record with your DNS provider. You may use `--no-wait` to not wait for validation or put `--validation-method` "dns-txt-token", "cname-delegation" 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/staticwebapp/hostname?view=azure-cli-latest#az-staticwebapp-hostname-set-examples

Comment: Yes, I have configured the Azure default URL with AWS under the domain I want it redirected to. I also tried these additional parameters and it continually tells me "ERROR: CNAME Record is invalid". However, when using the Azure UI directly to add the domain it works fine and validates itself.

Edit: I haven't tried `--no-wait`. I will try this

Comment: What is your CNAME record?

I noticed If you forgetting to add "www" in the domain field, domain field must be filled with subdomain, not regular domain without www.

Comment: There is no 'www' in it no. foobar.com as an example. But when I add it through the UI it doesn't have the 'www' either and it works just fine.

Comment: I have just created custom domain for my Azure Static Web App.
Domain provider is domain.com. I used CNAME record. 
Command: `az staticwebapp hostname set --name FOO --hostname test2.BAR.com`


az version - 2.40.0

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This worked for some reason even though I tried it previously. Shall we leave the solution here or draw it up as an answer? I'm quite new here so not sure how to close the question this way.

Comment: I will make an answer. Please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have already configured CNAME/TXT/ALIAS record with your DNS provider.

You may use `--no-wait` option to not wait for validation or use `--validation-method` "dns-txt-token" or "cname-delegation"

I would also suggest to verify your CNAME record, as often domain field must be filled with subdomain, not regular/naked domain.

Please also check if you are using the latest version of az cli.
You may check version using command `az version`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/staticwebapp/hostname?view=azure-cli-latest#az-staticwebapp-hostname-set-examples